# Android and GoogleMaps: disable the mapView dragging

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Android and GoogleMaps: Can I disable the mapView dragging without disable the pinch to zoom function?
Thx for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GestureDetector` and `SimpleOnGestureListener`, use `onFling()` to detect the distance between the path user did with his finger from the first touch till the release with `.getX()` and `getY()` from each `MotionEvent` and do nothing for `x > SOMEMAXVALUE` and `y > SOMEMAXVALUE`. I hope you'll find your way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest overridding `dispatchDraw()` in `MapView` class and check if the center is the one you want. Use `getController().setCenter(...)` to recenter the map. 
Just an alternative to what other people suggested.